# A probability to 6 in a dice

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I have a question about probability of a dice:
I'm reading know about the history of probability and I'm reading about the chance to get $6$ at dice of $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$.

If you get $6$ you win, otherwise - you lose....
The question is, how many times you need to roll the dice to  get a chance for a win  that is greater then $\frac{1}{2}$.

The solution I read is: 
$$1-\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^n$$
(and the answer is $n=4$...)

My question is:
Why the solution is not $$\frac{n}{6}$$ Because here also $n=4$ will give chance of getting win with more then $\frac{1}{2}$.

If you can explain me where is my mistake it will be great.

**::EDIT::**
I see what I missed! I need to use the [Inclusion–exclusion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle)
Now I'm understand where I wrong... :)

Thank you!

Comment: "The question is, how many times you need to roll the dice to a chance ..." - To a chance of what exactly? What chance/event are you trying to get a valuation for?

Comment: I fix my question :-)

Comment: Please _don't_ self-delete your question after getting an answer.

Comment: I understand my mistake... So if it's OK to delete it - I'll be glad :)

Comment: As an aside, the answer of $\frac{n}{6}$ is the correct answer *to a different question*.  $\frac{n}{6}$ counts the [expected value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value) of the number of sixes thrown in $n$ throws of a fair six-sided die.  This is, as mentioned already, not the same thing as the probability of getting at least one six.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An easy way to see your solution is wrong is to evaluate it for $n = 6$ or $n = 7$.

Your answer gives a 100% chance of throwing a 6 after 6 throws - which is incorrect.

Your answer gives a *116%* chance of throwing a 6 after 7 throws - which is even more obviously incorrect.

The deviation between your answer and the correct answer has to do with the fact that you can throw a 6 more than once. If we want to check the chance for $n = 2$, we can count the amount of cases where we threw a 6 on the first throw - $\frac{1}{6}$-th of them. Similarly, in one sixth of the cases we will throw a 6 on the second throw. However, the amount of cases where we threw a 6 on the first *or* second throw is not $\frac{1}{6} + \frac{1}{6}$, because we counted the case where we threw a six on both the first throw and second throw twice. So

$$ P = \frac{1}{6} +  \frac{1}{6} - \frac{1}{36} = \frac{11}{36} = 1 - (\frac{5}{6})^2.$$

Comment: Yes, that what I missed! Thank you!